# Save maps for offline usage in Android using OSMDroid

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am very new to OpenStreetMap, so this could be a noob question also.

So I have implemented basic OSM using OSMDroid library. But my main aim is to save the maps (from Internet) and then loading it (from SD Card) offline. Although there are ample examples on **How to load offline maps**.

Basic premise of those tutorial is to use **Mobile Altas Creator** on a desktop to save the maps, and then transfer them to phone's SD Card and then load them offline.

What I want to do is, I want the saving of the maps in Andoid itself. ***So is this possible to save maps in Android?***

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/42318/save-maps-for-offline-usage-in-android-using-osmdroid

Comment: There are already multiple questions and howtos about using offline tiles with osmdroid. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Agreed, there are ample tutorials for loading already saved maps with osmdroid, and those maps are saved using MOBAC. My question is to save the maps using osmdroid, or any other way, apart from osmdroid, to save maps in android.

Comment: It should be possible to save (i.e. to *cache*) currently displayed tiles in your application. In the end osmdroid just loads lots of separate images from a tileserver and sticks them together. So there is no reason why you should not be able to load these images from your local storage instead. I don't have a solution ready for you, however there are lots of results when searching for "osmdroid" and "cache".

Comment: My use case is to like, I visiting a country tomorrow and I don't want to get hefty roaming charges in my next billing. Caching wouldn't do, because I won't cache the whole country a day before. I just want to have an option to download the tiles in the app and use it tomorrow.

Comment: That's not directly possible because there are no official tile packages for specific countries available, unless you are building them yourself.

Comment: So, how to build tiles? Does that mean ill have to setup some Ubuntu server and download larger xml (or PBF) files and host them? Is that what building tiles myself mean?

Comment: Yes, for example by using Maperitive or TileMill. Alternatively you can just install one of many [Android apps for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android) that support vector maps, like OsmAnd or OruxMaps. Or create your own app with vector map support, for example by using Mapsforge instead of osmdroid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75259/discussion-between-anas-azeem-and-scai).

Comment: hello do you get any solution for your problem? I had same problem m new  to android and m unable to find any api that will support to download maps when online for offline use.

Comment: Sorry @charmi, I  couldn't help

Comment: no problem but atleast you can tell me that it is possible or not so that I can go further thats it if possible. Thank you

Comment: @charmi, it's been almost 2 years now. I wasn't able to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to [OSMBonusPack CacheManager feature](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/features).

The feature is available in the demo application OSMNavigator, so you can experiment if you want to see it in action.